# Declaring a finite sort in z3

Tags: python, z3

Let us assume I have a **finite** set {e1, e2, e3}. I want to be able to distinguish transitive constraints so I can handle this behavior:

```
from z3 import *

solver = Solver()
A = DeclareSort('A')
x = Const('x', A)
y = Const('y', A)
z = Const('z', A)
solver.add(x!=y)
solver.add(y!=z)
solver.add(x==z)

assert solver.check() != z3.sat
```

The only way I found to solve it is changing the last constraint with this one:

```
solver.add(ForAll([x,z],x==z))
```

Is this the way to model it? Is there any finite sort available? Should I need to add all the constraints declaring the elements different from each other?

**Some clarification:** Maybe is not a variable what I need, because {x == y, y == z, x == z } is clearly sat, but the behavior I want to model is more like this {x == 1, 2 == z, x == z } that is obviously unsat (assuming some finite sort like {1,2,3,4}).

Comment: The core of my problem is in the clarification I made at the end, I need a way to have a finite set of distinct values. I could encode this finite set with ints (i.e., use values like 1, 2, 3, ...), but maybe there is a more elegant way to solve it. My final result should be {x == a, b == z, x == z } is unsat, assuming a and b fixed values of this finite set and not variables / constants of some sort.

Comment: I found the answer: EnumSort

Answer (score 2):

What I was looking for was the EnumSort:

```
from z3 import *

solver = Solver()
S, (a, b, c) = EnumSort('round', ['a','b','c'])

x = Const("x", S)
z = Const("z", S)
solver.add(x==a)
solver.add(z==b)
solver.add(x==z)

assert solver.check() != z3.sat
```

Comment: Looks like you've a cut-paste error there, since `x` and `z` seem to both refer to the variable `x` as their name,